# JavaScript, Page Method, and Gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, gridview

I know now how to use the page method in JavaScript and ASP.Net (VB.Net) but it only limits me with single insertion. My problem is when I will insert to database in bulk with column items in gridview. It's not working and unfortunately, it doesn't say any error. This is I have so far:

**Server-side code (VB)**

```
<WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub SavetoDB(ByVal ans As Answers)
            Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CCQTConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblApplicantAns (Appnr, QID, answer) VALUES(@Appnr, @QID, @ans)")
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Appnr", ans.appnr)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QID", ans.qid)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", ans.ans)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    con.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End Sub

Public Class Answers
    Public Property qid() As String
        Get
            Return _qid
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _qid = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _qid As String
    Public Property ans() As String
        Get
            Return _ans
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _ans = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _ans As String
    Public Property appnr() As String
        Get
            Return _appnr
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _appnr = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _appnr As String
```

**JavaScript (AJAX)**

```
$(function () {

var gvDrv = document.getElementById("<%= grdQ.ClientID %>");
           for (i=1; i<gvDrv.rows.length; i++)
           {
             var cell = gvDrv.rows[i].cells;
             var q = cell[0].innerHTML;
             var a = cell[1].innerHTML;

                $("[id*=Button1]").bind("click", function () {
                    var ans = {};
                    ans.appnr = $("[id*=TextBox1]").val();
                    ans.qid = $(" + q + ").val();
                    ans.ans = $(" + a + ").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "English.aspx/SavetoDB",
                        data: '{ans: ' + JSON.stringify(ans) + '}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (response) {
                            alert("Time is up! Exam will proceed to next module.");
                            window.location = "Conf_English.aspx";
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
}
```

Comment: Do you have one button on each row or one button for the whole grid?

Comment: One button for the whole grid sir. The function that loops through gridview to get the data cannot refer to the instance member of a shared method, right? So I did the looping in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a single save button for the whole grid, then you have your client-script logic backwards. You will want to loop through each row of the grid in the click event handler for the button, instead of the other way around; like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id*=Button1]").bind("click", function() {
        var gvDrv = document.getElementById("<%= grdQ.ClientID %>");
        for (i = 1; i < gvDrv.rows.length; i++) {
            var cell = gvDrv.rows[i].cells;
            var q = cell[0].innerHTML;
            var a = cell[1].innerHTML;

            var ans = {};
            ans.appnr = $("[id*=TextBox1]").val();
            ans.qid = $(" + q + ").val();
            ans.ans = $(" + a + ").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "English.aspx/SavetoDB",
                data: '{ans: ' + JSON.stringify(ans) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("Time is up! Exam will proceed to next module.");
                    window.location = "Conf_English.aspx";
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

Now instead of calling the page method for each row in the grid you need to pass an array of values to the server-side ASP.NET AJAX Page Method instead of a single value. To leverage the `Answers` class you already have defined, we can build up a JavaScript array of objects that have property values that match the name of your properties in your class (i.e. `qid`, `ans`, etc.); like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id*=Button1]").bind("click", function() {
        var gvDrv = document.getElementById("<%= grdQ.ClientID %>");

        // Create array to hold x number of Answers instances
        var answers = new Array();

        // Loop through rows of grid
        for (i = 1; i < gvDrv.rows.length; i++) {
            var cell = gvDrv.rows[i].cells;
            var q = cell[0].innerHTML;
            var a = cell[1].innerHTML;

            // Build one answer object per row
            var ans = {};
            ans.appnr = $("[id*=TextBox1]").val();
            ans.qid = $(" + q + ").val();
            ans.ans = $(" + a + ").val();

            // Add single answer to array of answer objects
            answers.push(ans);
        }

        // Make one call to ASP.NET AJAX Page Method passing in array of answer values
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "English.aspx/SavetoDB",
            data: '{ans: ' + JSON.stringify(answers) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Time is up! Exam will proceed to next module.");
                window.location = "Conf_English.aspx";
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Finally, on the server-side in your ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, you will need to handle a list of `Answers` objects instead of a just a single `Answers` object, like this:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub SavetoDB(ByVal ans As List(Of Answers))
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CCQTConnectionString").ConnectionString

    ' Loop through each Answers object here
    For Each answer As Answers In ans   
        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblApplicantAns (Appnr, QID, answer) VALUES(@Appnr, @QID, @ans)")
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Appnr", answer.appnr)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QID", answer.qid)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ans", answer.ans)
                cmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    Next
End Sub
```